# How do you deal with sequeantial input shape error in tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am getting the following error in my code :-
`

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4, 3), found shape=(None, 3
```

`

and my code is

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
inum = np.array([[1,1,2],[2,25,6],[32,4,7],[8,9,0]], dtype="float")
onum = np.array([3,56,135,72],dtype="float")
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=(4,3))
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4)
l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4)
l3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0,l1,l2,l3])
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
history = model.fit(inum,onum,epochs=1200,verbose=False)
```

I am a beginner and I am very new so I don't have an idea what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The input shape does not contain the number of samples, it should just be (3,)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy   I tried it but it gives me value error when I try model.predct([2,2,4])

Comment: It is missing the samples dimension, a single sample would have shape (1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

The input shape should be the shape of a single sample. In your case, the input data has 4 rows and 3 columns. Each row represents a sample, and the sample size is (3,). As a result, the first layer's input shape should be (3,).

```
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=(3,))
```

Changing the input shape like above will help. Thank you!